# 1119: Access of possibly undefined property security through a reference with static type Class for using flash System.security.loadPolicyFile

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, youtube-api, adobe

I am developing an app and want to integrate the youtube API for Adobe Air.
However, I get the following error:
1119: Access of possibly undefined property security through a reference with static type Class.

My code is this:

```
import flash.system.SecurityDomain;
import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
import flash.system.LoaderContext;
import flash.system.Security;
System.security.loadPolicyFile("app:/crossdomain.xml");
Security.allowDomain("*");
```

I get this error in line 5 (System.security.loadPolicyFile("app:/crossdomain.xml");)
It seems that Flash does not even recognize this method.

Any ideas?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
System.loadPolicyFile("app:/crossdomain.xml");
```